# Splitting column of dataframe based on text characters in cells

Tags: python, pandas

I imported a .csv file with a single column of data into a dataframe that I am trying to clean up  by splitting the column based on various string occurrences within the cells. I've tried numerous means to split the column, but can't seem to get it to work. My latest attempt was using the following:

```
df.loc[:,'DataCol'] = df.DataCol.str.split(pat=':\n',expand=True)
df
```

The result is a dataframe that is still one column and completely unchanged. What am I doing wrong? This is my first time doing anything like this so please forgive the simple question.

Comment: Can you provide sample df and output?

Answer (score 0):

Df.loc creates a copy of the column you've selected - try replacing the code below with df['DataCol'], which references the actual column in the original dataframe.

```
df.loc[:,'DataCol']
```

Comment: What's the difference between that and the code in the OP?

Comment: Thanks @katardin. That change doesn't seem to have any effect however, unless I change what I'm passing as the parameter ("pat"). I can get the column to split on other strings but not the ':\n' that I want it to split on. Also, when I change the characters passed to pat, I end up overwriting DataCol, where what I'm actually trying to do is turn DataCol into two columns. Appreciate your help!